# F.cross_entropy raised "RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered. Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions."

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I met this error in loss function. An example below:

```
import torch
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

a = torch.Tensor([[-10.3353, -28.4371,   2.0768,   -4.2789,  -8.6644,  -6.0815],
        [-10.3353, -28.4371,   2.0768,   -4.2789,  -8.6644,  -6.0815],
        [-10.3353, -28.4371,   2.0768,   -4.2789,  -8.6644,  -6.0815],
        [-10.3353, -28.4371,   2.0768,   -4.2789,  -8.6644,  -6.0815]]).to(device)
b = torch.Tensor([ -100,  -1,  -100,  2456]).long().to(device)

loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(a,b,ignore_index=-1)
print(loss)
```

Then the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-29fe2d43a573> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(a,b,ignore_index=-1).to(device)
      2 loss

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3027     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3028         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3029     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   3030 
   3031 

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

I tried to set `export TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA=1` but still the same error raised.

Answer (score 0):

`b` should not be negative. Furthermore, the maximum value of `b` should be `a.shape[-1]`.

```
assert ((0 <= b) & (b < a.shape[-1])).all()
```

Your `b` does not satisfy these conditions.

> Target: If containing class indices, shape (C,), (N,C) or (N,d1,d2,...,dK) with K≥1 in the case of K-dimensional loss where **each value should be between [0,C)**. If containing class probabilities, same shape as the input and each value should be between [0,1].
>
> Source: [`F.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy.html)

---

This example adapted from the documentation of [`F.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy.html) works:

```
a = torch.randn(4, 6)
b = torch.randint(6, (4,), dtype=torch.int64)
loss = F.cross_entropy(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

change torch version 2.0.0+cu118 to 2.1.0.dev20230501+cu117 with :

`pip3 install numpy --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --force-reinstall --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu117`

Answer (score 0):

Apply a softmax function to a.

```
a = a.softmax(dim=1)
```

Additionally, b should not be negative values.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I increased the number of classes by 1 and was able to resolve it. My dataset had 2 output classes, and I was using Faster RCNN, for which I provided out_classes=2, and I was getting the error, after increasing it to 2+1, it solved my error

```
network.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_channels=in_features, num_classes=nc+1)
```